# How do I convert a string containing an array to an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have a string with an array of Json inside

```
"[{'firstname':'john','lastname':'doe'},{'firstname':'mary','lastname':'jane'}]"
```

How do I convert that to a string array of json?

For example the above would be

```
["{'firstname':'john','lastname':'doe'}","{'firstname':'mary','lastname':'jane'}"]
```

I then can use JObject.Parse on each of the elements of the array to make JObjects from the json.

Comment: Split he Stroug by the characters.

Comment: So that first string is your json? Or is a string inside you json? It's not really clear. If it is you json you should be able to deserailize it to an array.

Comment: Have you tried implementing your own solution yet?

Comment: Also you string (or it's contents) can't be json because it's using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @deathismyfriend: Processing Json by hand is a waste of time. There are plenty of libraries out there that will do it.

Comment: @MattBurland I never used Json didn't notice that was a Json string either. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: To expand on that, you can't easily split the string on `,` because there are matched and potentially nested pairs of `{}` with `,` inside. You have to count these pairs and only split when outside all `{}`. So let's say you implement that... but then you can get `{` or `}` inside a string in the JSON! It becomes easier to just write a full-blown JSON parser than handle all the edge cases, and at that point it's obviously not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is in a string variable `json`, the shortest way to get an array of JSON string is:

```
JArray.Parse(json).Select(o => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o)).ToArray();
```

However, the quickest way to get the `JObject`s is

```
foreach (JObject jObject in JArray.Parse(json)) {
     // do something with jObject
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You mention `JObject.Parse`, so you're using Json.NET, right? Do you really need the intermediate array of strings? If not, just use [`JArray.Parse`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) to parse the JSON in one go.

If the elements in the array all represent the same type and you want to convert them, you could convert them all into a strongly typed array using [`Values<T>()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Values__1.htm):

```
Person[] people = JArray.Parse(json).Values<Person>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string jsonString = "[{'firstname':'john','lastname':'doe'},{'firstname':'mary','lastname':'jane'}]";
string[] jsonStringArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonString)
            .Select(JsonConvert.SerializeObject)
            .ToArray();
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
class Person
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}
...
string jsonString = "[{'firstname':'john','lastname':'doe'},{'firstname':'mary','lastname':'jane'}]";
Person[] personArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person[]>(jsonString);
```